# Swagger schema with additionalProperties fails

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema, swagger-2.0

I'd like to post a JSON object within the body of a REST API call. The attribute `data`of this `DATA` object contains a mandatory `timestamp`attribute and then a series of various attributes depending on the source of the Data object. As far as I understood `additionalProperties`is meant for this and defaults to `false`or specifies the schema object for every non-defined attribute.

Following Swagger YAML

```
/my/path:
  post:
    tags: [Tag]
    description: Description
    parameters:
    - name: data
      in: body
      description: The actual data.
      required: false
      type: object
      schema:
        $ref: "#/definitions/Data"

definitions/
  Data:
    type: object
    properties:
      source:
        type: string
      data:
        type: object
        properties:
          timestamp:
            type: string
            format: date-time
        additionalProperties:
          type: string
```

should pass both objects send:

```
{
  "source": "A",
  "data": {
    "timestamp": "2016-10-26T01:12:40.329Z",
  }
}
```

and:

```
{
  "source": "B",
  "data": {
    "timestamp": "2016-10-26T01:12:40.329Z",
    "newProp":"newValue"
  }
}
```

However all I receive is a validation Error:
`ValidationError: child "data" fails because ["test" is not allowed]`

Is there anything I'm doing wrong or am I misinterpreting the attribute described at the docs:
[http://swagger.io/specification/](http://swagger.io/specification/%20*Swagger%20Specification*)

Comment: Alx, I don't know if the answer I've provided is too late to be helpful.  But if the information I've provided is not consistent with the results you're seeing, please provide some details about the validation error.  Specifically, where did you see that error? What Swagger processor or schema validator produced it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if [your solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40252381/776186) got your past the problem. I see a few differences from your original problem schema:

- `timestamp` now uses `date` instead of `datetime` format.
- `timestamp` is now required.
- `additionalProperties` is set to `true`.

However, there's a set of obscure limitations in Swagger with respect to additionalProperties, which we've [documented in detail here](https://support.reprezen.com/support/solutions/articles/6000162892-support-for-additionalproperties-in-swagger-2-0-schemas).

Essentially, while your original schema is perfectly valid according to the Swagger specification, the swagger-core Java library won't process it correctly.  It will discard either your explicitly defined `timestamp` property, or will discard `additionalProperties`.

The fix, surprisingly, is to extract the embedded schema for the `data` property to its own top-level schema definition:

```
definitions:

  Data:
    type: object
    properties:
      source:
        type: string
      data:
        $ref: "#/definitions/DataValues"

  DataValues:
    type: object
    properties:
      timestamp:
        type: string
        format: date-time
    additionalProperties:
      type: string
```

I think your revised schema won't work correctly, because `additionalProperties` boolean values of `true` or `false` are ignored by swagger-core. Apparently this was an oversight in the specification; Swagger [didn't intend](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/1437#issuecomment-226647555) to support this aspect of JSON Schema.

Answer (score -1):

I actually figured it out myself, for reference:

```
definitions/
  Data:
    type: object
    properties:
      source:
        type: string
      data:
        required:
         - timestamp
        type: object
        properties:
          timestamp:
            type: string
            format: date
        additionalProperties: true
```

Comment: `additonalProperties: true` is not supported in OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0 (which you use), it's only supported in OpenAPI 3.0.

Comment: thanks for your response and pointing out current updates I think meanwhile a lot has changed, so looking up the most current API docs is always recommended. Much appreciated